# Asp.Net Core: User session management system

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to set up a session management interface for users to essentially log out their sessions that may be active on other devices. However, I'm still somewhat new to Asp.Net Core 2.1 and am having trouble finding good documentation on the subject.

I thought about using the distributed SQL server cache system. However, after further inspection, I found that the keys for the distributed cache are not equal, as they shouldn't be, with the session id.

I also tried writing some middleware that stores the session id in a separate table with a many-to-one relationship with the user table. This table would have a sliding expiration dates and a tokens. If the session had a token, the session would be persisted.. My thought was to assign a token to the client using a cookie. That way if their session expired, it would lookup the session with the cookie token and, if one existed, log the corresponding user in. Then it would copy over the token and delete the old session. Kind of like a 'remember me' system. If the token is null and the session time was expired, it would be disposed of. If no session was found, or the user field is null, it would log the user out. If duplicate tokens were found, it would log all of the sessions with the corresponding token out. However, I'd rather use some kind of built in feature, if it exists, to minimize the risk in opening up unwanted security vulnerabilities.

I've also found examples where you can log another user out... But, because Asp.Net Identity is cookie-based, it allows the user to continue to use the site until their cookie expires... This would be undesirable in this scenario.

I know that Asp.Net had the IHttpSessionState, but I've been unable to find a similar interface in Core. Unfortunately, most solutions I've found either point to implementing a custom-made system, or they just show how to log the current session out.

Basically, is there already some kind of mechanism in Asp.Net Core that already implements something like this? If not, is there any specific interfaces that I should be researching and trying to implement? If not, should I resort to writing my own system? If so, are there any holes in my logic above?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about, pulled from Facebook's account management. I know that it's a much larger scope website, but I wouldn't think that such a feature would be extremely hard to integrate? Might be wrong though...

(Redacted some personal info)
[image]